Problem in Probability Theory and Functional Analysis
Let's consider the vector space  V  of bounded scalar functions, which includes the constant function 1. We assume that any uniform limit of a bounded monotonic sequence of functions from  V  also belongs to this space.
Let  D ⊂ V  be a subset that is closed under multiplication.
Can we prove that any bounded  σ(D) -measurable function belongs to the space  V ? Any hints or detailed explanations would be appreciated.

Blockquote


I made the requested edits.

What is $\sigma(C)$? If this is a minimal sigma-algebra for which all functions from $C$ is measurable, than what if $I=C=C[0,1]$? Not every bounded Borel function is in $I$

This statement is false in general. E.g., suppose that $C=I=C[0,1]$.
Then the function $1_{[0,1/2]}$ is bounded and $\sigma(C)$-measurable but not in $I$.

@NasimMamatkylov : Are you saying that, just because someone sets a task of proving a statement, the statement automatically becomes true? I will then set the task of proving that $0=1$.

@NasimMamatkylov : Do you have a further response to this answer?
